# POST and combine for more features

Tags: clockify

I want to combine a POST-API Request. How I can do it? I use Postman.

Here is an exemple: I want to create `Tag-Flags` to make two new tags.

```
{"name": "test"}
{"name": "test2"}
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ati0q.png)

Comment: You should declare more details

Comment: Hi, I want to create tags in Clockify. I want to create much tags, so I will use the API via POSTMAN. I don't want to create them one after the other. So I tryed {"name": "test"} {"name": "test2"}, but it don't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
 [{"name": "test"} , {"name": "test2"}]
```

https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: {
    "message": "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of com.clockify.adapter.http.v1.tag.TagRequest out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6862d9b6; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.clockify.adapter.http.v1.tag.TagRequest out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6862d9b6; line: 1, column: 1]",
    "code": 3002
}

Comment: Can you send a single record?  {"name": "MyTag"}